# How to pass attribute text as a variable to select a single node in xml using VBScript?

Tags: dom, vbscript, selectsinglenode, xml

I'm trying to select a single node in an xml file using VBscript using the following code

```
Set node = xmlDoc.selectingSingleNode(".//node()[@name = 'anything']")
```

This works perfectly if I write what I need to pass as a text.

But I need to pass this `'anything'` as a variable X

I tried the following but neither is working

```
xmlDoc.selectingSingleNode(".//node()[@name = X]")
xmlDoc.selectingSingleNode(".//node()[@name = '&X&']")
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate properly:

```
>> X = "abc"
>> WScript.Echo ".//node()[@name = '" & X & "']"
>>
.//node()[@name = 'abc']
```